# =image formula in google sheets doesnt work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-p3zN9B6ICuSCy6TALX4efLRVSIw0hNvzPdbI6Bbfk/edit?usp=sharing) and in cell I4 I have this formula

```
=IMAGE("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png")
```

It is [example formula from google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en) explaining how to use it. The problem is that it doesnt work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it helps, you can click on "Insert" ontop, select Image and insert the image URL instead!

Comment: Yes, but I need the image url to be accessible through API and if I insert the image this way, this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue **yesterday** but now **google seems to have solved this** already. Maybe there was some kind of outage or problem to retrieve the images.

Even the sheet you have shared is working right now:

[image: Proof of wrork]